# Как сделать появление тегов?

Tags: javascript

Привет всем! Есть такая разметка, необходимо, что бы отображалось в одной строке максимальное количество li и строчка заканчивалась ссылкой Ещё, при клике на ссылку Ещё показывались li, которые не поместились в одну строку.

```
<div class="b-tag">
  <ul class="b-tag__list short-text">
     <li id="1" class="b-tag__item">
        <a link="javascript:void(0);" title="" class="b-tag__link">1</a>
     </li>
     <li id="2" class="b-tag__item">
        <a link="javascript:void(0);" title="" class="b-tag__link"2</a>
     </li>
     <li id="3" class="b-tag__item">
        <a link="javascript:void(0);" title="" class="b-tag__link">3</a>
     </li>
     <li id="4" class="b-tag__item">
        <a link="javascript:void(0);" title="" class="b-tag__link">4</a>
    </li>
    <li id="5" class="b-tag__item">
        <a link="javascript:void(0);" title="" class="b-tag__link">5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="b-tag__item b-tag__item--more">
        <a link="javascript:void(0);" title="" class="b-tag__link b-tag__link--more">Еще</a>
    </li>
  </ul>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- В цикле проходим по `li` и смотрим их `top`. Как только он поменялся, они перестали помещаться в строку. Если все поместились, больше ничего не делаем.
- Вставляем кнопку <kbd>Ещё</kbd> в *начало* списка и проверяем, сколько теперь не помещается (она ведь заняла какое-то место).
- Перемещаем кнопку <kbd>Ещё</kbd> перед первым непомещающимся элементом.
- В css прописываем нужные свойства. Вероятно, это будет

  ```css
  .show-more ~ li {
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    display: none;
  }

  .show-more.shown ~ li {
    display: block;
  }
  ```